# How can I make PDF files in a Unity WebGL build?

Tags: pdf, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am in the process of making a Unity WebGL App and I would like the user to be able to download a status report which pulls-in info from the app.
So far I have tested SharpPDF with which i am able to generate a pdf in the editor and standalone builds but not in the webGL build.

Any ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make a jslib and use something like pdfkit.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I'll add that the reason why most of the c# pdf generators you'll find online won't work is because they take a dependency on either GDI or WPF, which are both windows specific.